# Laoding a high score in flash as2 using txt file

Tags: flash, file-upload, save, actionscript-2

as seen on the question above, i really need some help about loading and saving the scores in from the txt file to the flash and vice versa. Im still a newbie in flash and this is the last thing I would like to implement in my game. Im stuck about a week trying all the tutorials on the internet. Any help and advice is very appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Ok, i made something for you. See, how it happens.

---

1. First instantiate list of your players.
   we'll create: empty movie clip where to store textfields, empty array to store pulled information and a boolean variable for switch, needed later. Like this:

   ```
   players = ["tommy","tomm","tom","om","mmy"];
   this.createEmptyMovieClip("sc",1);
   var arr:Array = new Array();
   var done:Boolean;
   ```
2. Then, [LoadVars](http://docs.brajeshwar.com/as2/LoadVars.html) class will load 'scores.txt' file. Then for each player from array we'll push information to that array and sort it. Like this:

   ```
   loo = new LoadVars();
   loo.load("scores.txt");
   loo.onLoad = function() {
   for(el in players){
           arr.push(Number(this[players[el]]));}//##
       arr.sort(16);//16 stands for numeric
       arr.reverse();//descending
       done=true;}
   ```
3. And after sorted, we can dynamically place textfields and write value to their text propertie. Like:

   ```
   onMouseUp = function(){
   if(done==true){
       for(i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
           a = this.sc.createTextField("place"+i,i+100,Stage.width/2-25,i*30+30,50,25);
           a.text = arr[i];}
       done=false;}
   else{
       reload();}}
   ```
4. Also, notice how switch is working and that we call custom made 'reload' function. Add this to your file and run the movie.

   ```
   function reload():Void {
         _root.loadMovie(_root._url);}
   ```

The text file contents look like this - Same names as in players array, to correspond to. Write text in one line, with no line brakes.

```
tommy=112&tomm=20&tom=300&om=2&mmy=2922
```

//## if you want to leave scores with placeholder zeros in front of number, like '009', remove number function here and place number 2 for [sorting](http://docs.brajeshwar.com/as2/Array.html#sort()) options instead of 16 remove reversing array

Comment: it works like this : Step one - movie loads with all the scores and it parses values. you click once, score appears. click again, step one happens.

Comment: Oh, now i get it. Haha thnks a lot mate! :D (sorry kinda busy this week, late reply)

Answer (score 0):

create function that::

- :takes one parameter to indicate which place of file to return,

  for example, takes VarName as string [check this out a bit for strpos methods](http://docs.brajeshwar.com/as2/String.html)
- :reads txt in as string
- :then use indexOf("varName") to find a place where is info needed
- :then parse out next digits of text, holding score
- :finally return Number("123") <- so string of digits becomes int

then call function when needed:

- score = funcScore("tommy");
- trace(score*100); or whatever ^^ happy coding

Comment: Ok i got another question sorry, i'm making a scoreboard, which is it will display the ranking of the scores from the highest to lowest. And i'm using dynamic text to display it. And im using different text field for each scores. Is it possible to do, because i can't display any of them

Comment: well the same logics as previously i offered, plus dynamically parse list of movie clips by content value :D

Comment: ohh, okok i think i get you... Im gonna try some. thnks